# Division by zero with symbolic functions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mupad

If I want to make a plot of y=1/x in Matlab I can use the following code:

```
X=-10:0.1:10;
Y=1./(X);
plot(X,Y);
```

But I would like to use symbolic functions so I can differentiate them, so I have this code:

```
syms x;
f(x) = 1./x;

X=-10:0.1:10;
Y=f(X);
plot(X,Y);
```

Unfortunately I get here an error

> Error in MuPAD command: Division by zero. [_power]

This is reasonable as at some point it wil try to divide 1 by 0. How can I get this working so that it will return `Inf` when a division by zero occurs, just as in regular calculations of the form `a=6/0;`?

Comment: I'm not the question marked as duplicate of this fully answers this question. In particular, [`ezplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html) should be used to plot symbolic functions rather than `plot` (unless the functions are evaluated numerically).

Comment: @horchler - I can reopen the question if you believe you can adequately answer the question.  I thought the duplicate seemed to fit it, as long as you add the dirac functions in the right places.

Comment: @rayryeng: I tried the dirac function and that is ok, but not for differentiation. If `f` uses a dirac function then the derivative of `f` is not always correct.

Comment: @HéctorvandenBoorn - OK, I'll reopen to allow for horchler to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ezplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html) function can be used to directly plot symbolic functions and expressions.

```
syms x;
f(x) = 1/x;
ezplot(f,[-10 10]);
```

If you want to convert your expression to something that can be evaluated numerically, you can use [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert the symbolic function to a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html):

```
syms x;
f(x) = 1/x;
X = -10:0.1:10;
F = matlabFunction(f);
plot(X,F(X));
```

Why does't MuPAD return [`infinity`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/infinity.html) for `1/0`? In floating point, this is well-defined, but in mathematics, [divison by zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero) is undefined. If you want to evaluate your function entirely in MuPAD you'll need to [call underlying functions from Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html) and [handle errors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/handle-errors.html).